# Doctrine Native SQL many-to-many query

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I have a many-to-many relationship between `Students` and `Programs` with tables `student`, `program`, and `student_program` in my database.

I'm trying to join the two entities and perform some custom queries that require subqueries. This means that the Doctrine QueryBuilder cannot work because it does not support subqueries.

Instead, I'm trying the NativeSQL function and am making decent progress. However, when I try to `SELECT` something from the `Program` entity, I get the error `Notice: Undefined index: Bundle\Entity\Program in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/ObjectHydrator.php line 180`.

```
    $mapping = new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMappingBuilder($em);
    $mapping->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('Student', 's');
    $mapping->addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata('Program', 'p', 's', 'programs', array('id' => 'program_id'));
    // Query based on form 
    $sql = 'SELECT s.id, s.last_name, p.name <---- problem when this is added
            FROM student s
            JOIN program p
            ';

    $query = $em->createNativeQuery($sql, $mapping);

    $students = $query->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer but doctrine 2 does indeed support sub queries.  Just create a query then feed the dql into a where class.  This example is somewhat verbose but it works just fine:

```
public function queryGames($search)
{
    // Pull params
    $ages    = $this->getValues($search,'ages');
    $genders = $this->getValues($search,'genders');
    $regions = $this->getValues($search,'regions');

    $sortBy  = $this->getValues($search,'sortBy',1);
    $date1   = $this->getValues($search,'date1');
    $date2   = $this->getValues($search,'date2');
    $time1   = $this->getValues($search,'time1');
    $time2   = $this->getValues($search,'time2');

    $projectId = $this->getValues($search,'projectId');

    // Build query
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $qbGameId = $em->createQueryBuilder(); // ### SUB QUERY ###

    $qbGameId->addSelect('distinct gameGameId.id');

    $qbGameId->from('ZaysoCoreBundle:Event','gameGameId');

    $qbGameId->leftJoin('gameGameId.teams',   'gameTeamGameId');
    $qbGameId->leftJoin('gameTeamGameId.team','teamGameId');

    if ($projectId) $qbGameId->andWhere($qbGameId->expr()->in('gameGameId.projectId',$projectId));

    if ($date1) $qbGameId->andWhere($qbGameId->expr()->gte('gameGameId.date',$date1));
    if ($date2) $qbGameId->andWhere($qbGameId->expr()->lte('gameGameId.date',$date2));

    if ($time1) $qbGameId->andWhere($qbGameId->expr()->gte('gameGameId.time',$time1));
    if ($time2) $qbGameId->andWhere($qbGameId->expr()->lte('gameGameId.time',$time2));

    if ($ages)    $qbGameId->andWhere($qbGameId->expr()->in('teamGameId.age',   $ages));
    if ($genders) $qbGameId->andWhere($qbGameId->expr()->in('teamGameId.gender',$genders));

    if ($regions) 
    {
        // $regions[] = NULL;
        // $qbGameId->andWhere($qbGameId->expr()->in('teamGameId.org',   $regions));

        $qbGameId->andWhere($qbGameId->expr()->orX(
            $qbGameId->expr()->in('teamGameId.org',$regions),
            $qbGameId->expr()->isNull('teamGameId.org')
        ));

    }
    //$gameIds = $qbGameId->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
    //Debug::dump($gameIds);die();
    //return $gameIds;

    // Games
    $qbGames = $em->createQueryBuilder();

    $qbGames->addSelect('game');
    $qbGames->addSelect('gameTeam');
    $qbGames->addSelect('team');
    $qbGames->addSelect('field');

    $qbGames->addSelect('gamePerson');
    $qbGames->addSelect('person');

    $qbGames->from('ZaysoCoreBundle:Event','game');

    $qbGames->leftJoin('game.teams',   'gameTeam');
    $qbGames->leftJoin('game.persons', 'gamePerson');
    $qbGames->leftJoin('game.field',   'field');

    $qbGames->leftJoin('gameTeam.team',     'team');
    $qbGames->leftJoin('gamePerson.person', 'person');

    $qbGames->andWhere($qbGames->expr()->in('game.id',$qbGameId->getDQL())); // ### THE TRICK ###

    switch($sortBy)
    {
        case 1:
            $qbGames->addOrderBy('game.date');
            $qbGames->addOrderBy('game.time');
            $qbGames->addOrderBy('field.key1');
            break;
        case 2:
            $qbGames->addOrderBy('game.date');
            $qbGames->addOrderBy('field.key1');
            $qbGames->addOrderBy('game.time');
            break;
        case 3:
            $qbGames->addOrderBy('game.date');
            $qbGames->addOrderBy('team.age');
            $qbGames->addOrderBy('game.time');
            $qbGames->addOrderBy('field.key1');
            break;
    }

    // Always get an array even if no records found
    $query = $qbGames->getQuery();
    $items = $query->getResult();

    return $items;
}
```